# Escape 'At sign' (@) in Oracle SQLPlus script filename

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When trying to execute a script in SQLPlus that has an "At Sign" (@) in the filename, the @ symbol is expanded to the SID:

`SQL> @ foo@bar.sql
SP2-0310: unable to open file "fooorclbar.sql"`

`SQL> START foo@bar.sql
SP2-0310: unable to open file "fooorclbar.sql"`

Is there a way to escape the @ symbol in SQLPlus?

Comment: `start "foo@bar.sql"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `escchar` SQL*PLUS system variable to `@`.

```
SQL> set escchar @
```

Here is an example:

File `foo@bar.sql` contains `select 1 from dual` statement;

```
SQL> @foo@bar.sql

         1
----------
         1
```